# Method to Cycle Through Multiple UITextFields in Different View Controllers

Tags: swift2

I have to view controllers: a sign-up view controller and a log-in view controller. The sign-up view controller has 3 text fields; username, password, and email. The log-in view controller has 2; username and password.

I wrote a method in my sign-up view controller that cycles through the text fields, and I want to the log-in view controller to have the same functionality, but I don't want to subclass.

Is there a good way to give both view controllers the same functionality without code duplication, maybe by utilizing some of Swift 2's features; protocol extensions or something else?

What about creating an extension of `UIViewController` and calling that method on `self` from the appropriate text field delegate methods?

Currently, I just store the text fields in an array in their respective view controller and then I use that in the text field delegate method. I'm not quite sure how to give them the same functionality without subclassing, which I don't want to do.

I didn't post any code because I'm not looking for an easy solution. I'm looking for an answer that directs me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an extension for `UIViewController` that contains the methods that I want access to in any view controller.